# How to setup restriction for view in a table tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is code of my view file, it shows multiple columns for the table.

The restriction is working but columns are multiple.

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>

    <% obj.each do |article| %>
        <% if logged_in? && current_user == article.user %>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Show</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Updated At</th>
        <% end %>

    <% end %>
    </tr>


    <% obj.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= article.title %></td>
    <td><%= article.description %></td>
    <% if logged_in? && current_user == article.user %>

        <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(article), class: "btn btn-primary" %> </td>
        <td><%= link_to "show", article_path(article), class: "btn btn-success" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Delete", article_path(article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you Sure?"}, class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>

        <td> <%= article.user.username if article.user %> </td>
        <td> <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %> ago.</td>
        <td> <%= time_ago_in_words(article.updated_at) %> ago.</td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>

    <% end %>
</table>

<%= link_to 'Back', root_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
```

[image]

Comment: Whats the desired result? Do you want the "Show", "Edit", "Delete" links to only appear if the user can edit the article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the `thead` depending on the value of `obj`, try leaving just the second iteration, to print each tr, maybe something like:

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user == article.user %>
  <tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Show</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Created By</th>
    <th>Created At</th>
    <th>Updated At</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <% obj.each do |article| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= article.title %></td>
        <td><%= article.description %></td>
        <% if logged_in? && current_user == article.user %>
          <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(article), class: "btn btn-primary" %> </td>
          <td><%= link_to "show", article_path(article), class: "btn btn-success" %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "Delete", article_path(article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you Sure?"}, class: "btn btn-danger" %></td>
          <td> <%= article.user.username if article.user %> </td>
          <td> <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %> ago.</td>
          <td> <%= time_ago_in_words(article.updated_at) %> ago.</td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understand by your title question, you want to prevent the view of all your table . So

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user == article.user %>
   <table class="table table-responsive">
      <tr>
         ...
         the rest of the code for show the table
         ....
   </table>
<% end %>
```

This will hide the view of the whole table and It only will be shown for the article author

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're iterating each `article` in `obj` and outputting a header *each* time the currently logged in user is the articles user:

```
<% obj.each do |article| %>
    <% if logged_in? && current_user == article.user %>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Show</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
        <th>Updated At</th>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You probably only want to show the header a single time if the user is logged in and is the user of **any** `article`, Ruby has a method for that, [`Enumerable#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F). So something like this should be what you're looking for:

```
<% if logged_in? && obj.any? { |article| current_user == article.user } %>
  <th>Edit</th>
  <th>Show</th>
  <th>Delete</th>
  <th>Created By</th>
  <th>Created At</th>
  <th>Updated At</th>
<% end %>
```

This should only output one set of the headers if the user is logged in and is the author of any article on the page, instead of one set of headers per article authored.